# Rhino mocks how to check if a method was called by another method from the same class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I ran into a bit of a trouble while testing one of my classes.
I have an abstract class which contains one public method and two protected abstract once.
I need to test weather public method calls one of the abstract once.

Heres an example of how my code looks like:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public string DoSomething(stirng input)
    {
        var output = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var currentChar in input)
        {
            output.Append(DoSomethingElse(currentChar));
        }

        return output.ToString();
    }

    protected abstract char DoSomethingElse(char charToChange);
}

public class B : A
{
    protected override char DoSomethingElse(char charToChange)
    {
        var changedChar = charToChange;
        // Some logic changing charToChange's value
        return changedChar;
    }
}
```

Because `DoSomethingElse()` is protected I've created a class that publishes that method

```
public class BPublisher : B
{
    public virtual new char DoSomethingElse()
    {
        return base.DoSomethingElse()
    }
}
```

My question is how do I test the fact that `DoSomething()` called `DoSomethingElse()` using 
Rhino mocks?

P.S. I have tried using `Expect` and `AssertWasCalled` but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare another method using `new`, it doesn't have anything to do with your original protected method. Because it is not virtual, you can not mock it. Making it virtual and mock that is kind of weird, because you derive a test class to create a mock from.

I would actually not try to use a mock in this case. Why not return a useful result in a property?

```
public class BPublisher : B
{
    public readonly StringBuilder chars = new StringBuilder();

    public virtual new char DoSomethingElse(char charToChange)
    {
        chars.Append(charToChange);
        return charToChange;
    }
}

var a = new BPublisher();
a.DoSomething("abc");
Assert.AreEqual("abc", a.chars.ToString());
```

At the end it is still weird. It's sometimes hard to test abstract base classes. You may also consider to make `DoSomethingElse` public.

Comment: Checking weather the output of `DoSomething()` and `a.chars.ToString()` are equal is a good test. but lets say I decided to completely change the logic of the `DoSomethingElse()` method, I still want `DoSomething()`'s test to pass as its logic haven't changed.

Comment: Also for example, if an empty string was sent to `DoSomething()`, I would like to see that `DoSomethingElse()` wasn't called at all.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to test this ? Unit testing should test the *output* based on a set of *inputs*. How you implement this is of no concern to the test (in *output* you could include the resultant members/state of the object)

e.g. if I refactor your class heavily, I still want the tests to pass. e.g. if I give you an input do I still get the output. I don't really want the tests to fail if the implementation differs (since I don't really care about the implementation)

Comment: True, I can indeed test the input and the out of class A, but I already tested that `DoSomethingElse()` works, therefore now I only need to see if its called properly. I don't want to test the implementation I want to test the call of `DoSomethingElse()` in `DoSomething()`

Comment: And again, I question why you want to test the *implementation* as opposed to the results that you get when you invoke DoSomething()

Comment: Modified the example perhaps now it would be more clear why I want to test the call of `DoSomethingElse()`.

Comment: @Brian: normally I agree. But abstract base classes have another kind of interface: the virtual members which are meant to be overridden. It makes sense to test if the base class itself calls my derived class. In other words: the user which expects the "output" is not a caller from outside, but a deriving class.